# Shopify: auto-update Price when Quantity changed in Cart page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to update Price immediately once the buyer increase or decrease the Quantity using Plus & Minus buttons?

Here is the Quantity Picker code:

```
<div class="plus button">-</div>
<input type="number" name="updates[]" id="updates_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__product-qty" value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="0" data-id="{{ item.key }}">
<div class="minus button">+</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: james what have you try so far ?

Comment: I tried to add `onblur="this.form.submit();"` but it works only when the customer clicks inside Quantity field and enter the quantity manually using keyboard numbers

Comment: This comment to re-rank the post, anyone can help me!